# Enabling HTTPS with go-daddy's ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am new to handling procedures related to the installation of SSL certificate in Linux Centos 7 with Apache, so here is the sequence of events happened so far,

1. we got the SSL certificate
2. Due to some reasons, we disabled the secure connection (HTTPS to HTTP)
3. we got the certificate renewed (it is not downloaded yet.)

Now, I would like to know the procedure to enable HTTPS again.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: should I need to remove previous SSL related files !! If so how can remove all files which are related to this? OR If its possible to update SSL then what procedure should I have to follow now.so that I can use previous files to enable HTTPS back.